# Shader fails to draw entities?

Tags: opengl, glsl, 2d

The problem is that when I want to use the shader my objects are not rendered.

I expected the output to be red entites. This is very confusing to me.

I have two basic shaders:

**vertex shader :**

```
#version 150

in vec2 attribute_position;

out vec3 v_color;

void    main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(attribute_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    
    v_color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

**and fragment shader :**

```
#version 150

in vec3 v_color;

out vec4 out_color;

void    main(void)
{
    out_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);
}
```

This is how I loaded my shaders:

```
public ShaderProgram(GL2 gl, String vertexShader, String fragmentShader) {
        vertexShaderId = loadShader(gl, vertexShader, GL2.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragmentShaderId = loadShader(gl, fragmentShader, GL2.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        
        programId = gl.glCreateProgram();
        gl.glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
        gl.glAttachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);

        gl.glBindAttribLocation(programId, 0, "attribute_position");
        
        gl.glLinkProgram(programId);
        gl.glValidateProgram(programId);

        int[] status = new int[1];
        gl.glGetProgramiv(programId, GL2.GL_LINK_STATUS, status, 0);
        if (status[0] == GL2.GL_FALSE) {
            int[] error = new int[1];
            gl.glGetProgramiv(programId, GL2.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, error, 0);

            byte[] log = new byte[error[0]];
            gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(programId, error[0], null, 0, log, 0);
            
            throw new RuntimeException("Error lniking the program: " + new String(log));
        }

        gl.glDetachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
        gl.glDetachShader(programId, fragmentShaderId);
        gl.glDeleteShader(vertexShaderId);
        gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderId);
    }

    private int loadShader(GL2 gl, String shader, int type) {
        int shaderId = -1;
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(shader), "UTF-8");
            String source = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            scanner.close();
            
            if ((shaderId = gl.glCreateShader(type)) == GL2.GL_INVALID_ENUM) {
                System.out.println("error 1");
                System.exit(1); //TODO
            }
            
            gl.glShaderSource(shaderId, 1, new String[] { source }, new int[] { source.length() }, 0);
            gl.glCompileShader(shaderId);

            int[] status = new int[1];
            gl.glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL2.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, status, 0);
            if (status[0] == GL2.GL_FALSE) {
                int[] error = new int[1];
                gl.glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL2.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, error, 0);

                byte[] log = new byte[error[0]];
                gl.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, error[0], null, 0, log, 0);

                throw new RuntimeException("Error compiling the shader " + shader + ": " + new String(log));
            }    
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("error 3" + exception);
            System.exit(1); //TODO:
        }

        return shaderId;
    }

    public void start(GL2 gl) {
        gl.glUseProgram(programId);
    }

    public void stop(GL2 gl) {
        gl.glUseProgram(0);
    }
```

And in my Scene render method, I do gl.glUseProgram(programId); before and gl.glUseProgram(0); after the drawing.

```
if (shader == null)
    shader = new com.sandbox.StaticShader(graphics);
shader.start(graphics);
for (Layer layer : gameObjects.values()) {
    for (Component component : layer.objects) {
       if (component.isOpaque()) {
          component.render(graphics);
       }
     }
}
shader.stop(graphics);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of a shader stage is linked to the input of the next shader stage by its name (except when you use a layout qualifier). See [interface matching rules between shader stages](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Interface_matching).
Therefore, the name of the vertex shader output must match the name of the fragment shader input.

e.g. Use the name `v_color` instead of `out_color`/`in_color`:

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 150

in vec2 attribute_position;

out vec3 v_color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(attribute_position, 0.0, 1.0);
    
    v_color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 150

in vec3 v_color;

out vec4 out_color;

void main(void)
{
    out_color = vec4(v_color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I have rename in_color to v_color but the problem is same, My screen is still empty.
(I think that the output and the input mached my version)

Comment: @AmauryLeRouxDupeyron So you did it wrong. Please note that my code has been tested a and works fine. Have you renamed the variable in the fragment shader?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, can the problem be about positions ? or in the canvas preparation something to enable ?

Comment: How can i debug shaders? At least, I know that the error might be in my shaders declaration or use because I have no problem without it.

Comment: Can you link me your testing code ? Thanks